# libapache2-mod-php7.2 Not working

Tags: apt, apache2, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress, but then it stopped working. I then firgured out that it had something to do with apache2. I got that working but now when I get to the webpage, instead of executing the php file, I get the code. I tried re-installing the php apache2 module, but got this:

`Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-php7.2_7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php7.2 (7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.2 (7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Module mpm_event disabled.
Enabling module mpm_prefork.
apache2_switch_mpm Switch to prefork
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.2 (--configure):
 installed libapache2-mod-php7.2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: I have fixed the problem and it is working. All i did was `sudo apt remove --purge libapache2-mod-php7.2` and then `sudo apt install libapache-mod-php*`.

Comment: Nice one Larry, make this an answer so people can upvote

Answer (score 9):

It work for me same - sudo apt remove --purge libapache2-mod-php7.2 and then sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php*

Comment: Same happened to me for `libapache2-mod-php7.4` and purging also works.